# Why does my ASP.NET WebAPI file handler not return files across all browsers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to return an Excel file from an ASP.NET Web API method. I'm using Web API as a part of my ASP.NET web forms application. Actually the Web API method may return other file types but I'm trying to stabilize with Excel files right now.

I am able to access the ASP.NET Web API across user agents, but for some reason I can't figure out how to get the Web API to successfully return the Excel file to all user agents. For some reason, only IE seems to be able to interpret the HTTP response and serve the given requested Excel file. Fiddler interprets the HTTP response and recognizes that a binary file is returned as well. Current code follows:

```
public class FilesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage GetExcelFile(int id)
    {
        ExcelFile excelFile = new ExcelService().GetExcelFile(id);
        HttpResponseMessage result;
        if (excelFile == null)
        {
            result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            return result;
        }

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(
            string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",
            System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/"),
            new ConfigUtilities().GetTemplateReportFilesRootPath(),
            excelFile.Name));

        if (!fi.Exists)
        {
            result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            return result;
        }

        long length = fi.Length;
        result = new HttpResponseMessage();
        result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

        var stream = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.CopyTo(memStream);
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memStream.ToArray());// new StreamContent(stream);

        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
        new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName =
                String.Format(@"{0}", excelFile.DisplayName.Replace(@"""", "-"))
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = length;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Originally my source code to stream the file was as below, but I've revised it dozens of times with little trial and error attempts to return files, so that it looks like the first code block now:

```
    result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
    new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName =
            String.Format(@"{0}", excelFile.DisplayName.Replace(@"""", "-")),
        Size = fi.Length
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fi.Length;

    return result;
```

IE recognizes the file from the HTTP response. Chrome and FireFox though both respond differently. Chrome is as follows:

[image: Chrome example]

FireFox is as follows:

[image]

I've read all of the stackoverflow threads and Google'd everything that I could but I can't seem to resolve the issue. I'm simply trying to access the WebAPI from a standard HTTP GET request, so that I can serve files through standard HTTP hyperlink tags on a webpage.

Fiddler shows the following:

[image]

And the following on the raw view:

[image]

Comment: Don't use `string.Format` for combining paths! use a `Uri` or `UriBuilder`.

Comment: what does the response actually look like?

Comment: I'd take a look using Fiddler and see what is coming down the pipe. That might give you some hints.

Comment: Just added Fiddler output from the webapi invocation

Answer (score 2):

Here is an official sample, to show proper file download. You can find the full sample [here](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/ActionResults/ReadMe.txt).

Action Result:

```
public class OkFileDownloadResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly ApiController _controller;

    public OkFileDownloadResult(string localPath, string contentType, string downloadFileName,
        ApiController controller)
    {
        if (localPath == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localPath");
        }

        if (contentType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("contentType");
        }

        if (downloadFileName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("downloadFileName");
        }

        if (controller == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controller");
        }

        LocalPath = localPath;
        ContentType = contentType;
        DownloadFileName = downloadFileName;
        _controller = controller;
    }

    public string LocalPath { get; private set; }

    public string ContentType { get; private set; }

    public string DownloadFileName { get; private set; }

    public HttpRequestMessage Request
    {
        get { return _controller.Request; }
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute());
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage Execute()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(MapPath(LocalPath)));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(ContentType);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = DownloadFileName
        };
        return response;
    }

    private static string MapPath(string path)
    {
        // The following code is for demonstration purposes only and is not fully robust for production usage.
        // HttpContext.Current is not always available after asynchronous calls complete.
        // Also, this call is host-specific and will need to be modified for other hosts such as OWIN.
        return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);
    }
}
```

Extensions methods for ApiController

```
public static OkFileDownloadResult Download(this ApiController controller, string path, string contentType)
    {
        string downloadFileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        return Download(controller, path, contentType, downloadFileName);
    }

    public static OkFileDownloadResult Download(this ApiController controller, string path, string contentType, string downloadFileName)
    {
        if (controller == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controller");
        }

        return new OkFileDownloadResult(path, contentType, downloadFileName, controller);
    }
```

And use pattern inside a controller:

```
[Route("file")]
public OkFileDownloadResult GetFile()
{
    return this.Download("Download.xml", "application/xml");
}
```

Comment: It looks like ApiController.Execute() in your example is doing the same thing that I'm doing. I integrated this full example and the same issue occurs - identical to my issue that I'm asking about.

Comment: could it be they don't recognize the extension .xslm ?

Comment: Not sure. I've tried Excel mime types and application/octet-stream, and it seems to be getting returned when inspected with fiddler. I wonder if it's a missing http header, or some other little thing possibly related to using the web api in a classic asp.net forms application. All examples and demos that I can find aren't working. At least IE works for now.

Comment: Here is another suggestion. Serve the file as static files directly from IIS. Drop the in a content folder without ANY ASP.NET application in the site. Are you still seeing issues with Chrome and FireFox?

Comment: Yes that works. I can access the Excel files directly across all browsers

Comment: Cool, now compare the differences between the responses in a WebAPI request and the requests that work :)